# How to find the originator of a file with an SVN command

Tags: svn

So, basically I'd like to find all the files that a person on the team has originated.  My thinking was to find the originator of all the files, and from that set limit it to those that match the originator I'm interested in.

Is there some combination of SVN commands that might make this easy?

Thanks,
L-

Answer (score 0):

svn log  will tell you the history of every change made to that file - but you can't just get the oldest record.

svn blame  will tell you who changed/wrote every single line of that file most recently.

I don't think there's any better ways, sorry!

Comment: The oldest change should be the file addition to the svn trunk, and the person who is blamed for that change is the user who originated the file.  SVN LOG is slow as anything though, so it's not going to be a solution you like unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the top of your current checkout and do:

```
svn log -v | less
```

search in less with for the person's name so:

```
/name
```

If that checkout has a file with an `A` next to it, then he added that file to the repository.  Aka, he probably created it.